# How to calculate sum of values returned in getter?

Tags: java, arrays, sum

This Following code prints out this
21
48
68
96

But I want it to print just the total amount which is 96 how ?

public int totalContribution() {

```
    for(ClubMember c : members) {


        if(c != null) {
            totalContribution += c.getContribution();
        }

        //System.out.println(c.getContribution());
        System.out.println(totalContribution);
```

Comment: What's members?   List or array?

Comment: It is an Arraylist

Answer (score 1):

Move `System.out.println` out of the for loop.
You're printing the accumulative sum from every loop.

```java
for(ClubMember c : members) {
    if(c != null) {
        totalContribution += c.getContribution();
    }
}

System.out.println(totalContribution);
```

Comment: Can you show more context of codes with `totalContribution` declaration and `return` statements inside the for loop?

Comment: Great that you've made it. You shouldn't have any statements after the return statement that no flow can pass by it. None of the flows will be reach the statements after the return statement because the flow inside the method will end when it reaches the return statement.

Comment: This is the most simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out every iteration, so you get a cumulative sum which is printing out multiple times. To fix this, move the print statement outside the `for` loop and it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to stream the list and compute the sum.

```
public int totalContribution() {
    return members.stream()
                .mapToInt(ClubMember::getContribution).sum();
}
```